# Record audio/video in skype for business online - skype web sdk

Tags: record, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I did not find any information available online on how to record a meeting(audio or video) scheduled using skype for business online (skype web sdk).

All I see is information only on [skype for business onpremises](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Record-and-play-back-a-Skype-for-Business-meeting-6d1dd3c5-ded7-4935-8db0-d6d7173c482f) which full clients to record and store meeting in local storage.

It will be very grateful if someone can provide references on recording audio/video using skype for business - online.

Comment: did you manage to find a way to record audio/video calls with skype for web sdk ?

Comment: I could not find, still looking for ways to record audio or video using skype web sdk.

Comment: I think user has to select recording option from Skype video screen..  what all features did you implement with Skype for web sdk. are you successful in making video call between 2 participants? if yes, do you see recording options on the video call screen?

Comment: I am successful in implementing video call between 2 participants i.e one to one, but multiparty video conversion did not worked for me

Comment: Nice.  do you have your code sample in github or anywhere i can access.  I am evaluating skype for business if it fit's into our system or not.. It would be great if i can see it working...   And when the participants are on video call, do they see any option on screen to `start recording` or similar ?

Comment: did you run the samples https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/samples ..  I could make multi user video conference using these samples..

Comment: Samples shared are for App SDK, our use case was for web SDK ie for browsers. We don't see any option for recording in web SDK.

Comment: https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2016/03/skype-web-sdk-online-setting-everything-up-step-by-step-guide/ this might help you for getting started.

Answer (score 1):

Skype for business online does not support recording as of now.

Comment: Thanks the information, can you share reference if there?

Answer (score 1):

Now Skype for Business Online Plan 2 supports Audio and Video Recordings.  You can find the detailed feature comparision [here](https://products.office.com/en-gb/skype-for-business/compare-plans)

After a lot of research, i have decided to use `Skype Media bot` along with `Skype Web SDK` to record audio and video conversations.

1. Create a Skype Media Bot and add Skype for Business as channel.
2. Register this bot with Skype for Business online ( Only Tenant Administrator can do that)
3. Make sure in each conference, this Skype Bot is also invited by default. So this bot is a participant in each conference call. It records audio and video.
4. Skype Bot has simple interface to Record, Respond, Convert audio to text and many more features.

Github samples can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp)