# How to record Skype meeting video with Trusted Application API(Skype for Business)

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I am trying to create Service-side video meeting recording function for Skype for Business Online.

The [Trusted Application API Reference](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-docs/blob/master/Skype/Trusted-Application-API/docs/Trusted_Application_API_GeneralReference.md) includes "Service-side meeting recording" as an Example solutions.

I thought that the Trusted Application API has a function to record a meeting video on the server side. However, I could not find the document in which it was written.

[Record audio/video in Skype for Business Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983938/) includes a *Skype Media bot* example but there is also a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-RealTimeMediaCalling/issues/25) that mentions:

> Also please note that group conference in Skype has also been disabled for bots due to privacy reasons.

How can I make a meeting video recording on the server side?